# Kotlin custom actionbar title sometimes shows wrong title for split second

Tags: android-fragments, kotlin, android-actionbar

I've created custom actionbar titles for each fragment in my kotlin app. However sometimes it shows the fragmentname for a split second before showing the custom title.

This is the code I have in each fragment:

```
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val binding = inflate<FragmentHomeBinding>(
            inflater,
            R.layout.fragment_home, container, false
        )
        ////
        //some binding
        ////

        return binding.root
    }

 override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Custom"
    }

    override fun onResume() {
        super.onResume()
        (activity as AppCompatActivity).supportActionBar?.title = "Custom"
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out I could just edit the label in navigation.xml to save a lot of trouble